# UpdatePanel triggers not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have problem with UpdatePanel (ASP.Net WebForms, .Net 4.0). Here is code:

```
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <h2>Poruke</h2>
            <div class="row">
                <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" />
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="msgListUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="False">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <asp:ListBox ID="msgList" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="msgList_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" ClientIDMode="AutoID"></asp:ListBox>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <asp:ListBox ID="conversationList" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID"></asp:ListBox>
                            <br class="divider" />
                            <p>
                                Odgovor: <span>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="replyTxtbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></span>
                            </p>
                            <asp:Button ID="sendBtn" runat="server" Text="Pošalji" OnClick="sendBtn_Click" EnableViewState="false" ClientIDMode="AutoID" />
                        </div>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="msgList" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"/>
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

and this is codebehind...

```
    int userIdCookie = 0;
    message selected = new message();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
        }

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Int32.TryParse(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name, out userIdCookie))
            {
                message msg = new message();
                var allMsg = msg.allMessagesFormatted().Distinct().ToList();
                msgList.DataSource = allMsg;
                msgList.DataBind();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // test only!
            replyTxtbox.Text = msgList.SelectedIndex.ToString();
            msgListUpdatePanel.Update();
        }
    }

    protected void msgList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        message msg = new message();

        var allMsg = msg.allMessagesFormatted().Distinct().ToList();
        msgList.DataSource = allMsg;

        IList<message> boundList = (IList<message>)msgList.DataSource;

        selected = boundList[msgList.SelectedIndex];
        var conversation = msg.allMessagesFormatted().FindAll(x => x.conversationGuid == selected.conversationGuid);

        conversationList.DataSource = conversation;
        conversationList.DataBind();
    }

    protected void sendBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(selected.recipientId != 0)
        {
            message newmsg = new message();
            newmsg.senderId = userIdCookie;
            newmsg.recipientId = selected.recipientId;
            newmsg.subject = selected.subject;
            newmsg.messageTxt = replyTxtbox.Text;
            newmsg.conversationGuid = selected.conversationGuid;
            newmsg.time = DateTime.Now;
            newmsg.Add();
        }
    }
```

msgList gets populated fine but when i change selection, nothing happens - its SelectedIndex event never fires. If I set AutoPostBack="true" to this listbox, it reloads page (which is exactly what I am trying to avoid).

To sum up - when i click on item in ListBox inside UpdatePanel, nothing happens (event isn't fired). I want to avoid page reload when selected index changes. I've tried dozen of solutions (ClientID, AsyncPostBack, "regular" PostBack triggers and I guess i missed one simple detail and it's driving me mad.

Can anyone help?

edit - as @mason pointed out, problem was in overidden `message.ToString()` method that contained `\r\n` chars which caused problems in postback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will receive a JavaScript error in your browser's console.

> Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Invalid postback
>   or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page
>   EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes,
>   this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events
>   originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If
>   the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.
>   MsAjaxJs?v=c42ygB2U07n37m_Sfa8ZbLGVu4Rr2gsBo7MvUEnJeZ81:1 Uncaught
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Invalid postback
>   or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page
>   EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes,
>   this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events
>   originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If
>   the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.

You can see a simpler version if you use:

```
msgList.DataSource = new List<string>(){"A\r\n","B\r\n","C\r\n"};
```

When you watch it in the browser tab, you'll see POST request sent to the server, but on the server side the `Page_Load` method won't get hit at all.

The fix is either to not use `\r\n` characters in the data being used for the ListBox or to follow the directions to register it at [ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms223397%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Unbelievable. It works just fine when i add `msgList.DataSource= new List<string>(){"A","B","C"};`

And problem is in overridden `.ToString()` in `Message` class. I put `\r\n` in method and something didn't like that. When i removed that, everything else worked just fine.

Problem solved!

Comment: @nighthawk I updated with solution. Anyways, I reccomend never using UpdatePanel. Instead, switch to using [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) along with a client side scripting framework (such as jQuery) that makes AJAX easy.

Comment: I'll probably switch it to WebAPI since UpdatePanel causes a lot of problems (like this one) and it slows pages down.