# AJAX partial postback panel breaks my buttons?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, asp.net-ajax

So, I've been chasing this for a few days and I think I misdiagnosed the problem.  I have an ASPX page with a few buttons and placeholders whose visibility changes based on queries.  Everything works fine.  But then I added a textbox with datetime from the server, inside an asp panel.  The content within the panel works fine, and I've tried several scenarios.

Regardless of how I do it, I find that my buttons, which are outside of this panel, aren't working... I'm not getting to the click event at all.  I've come to the conclusion that the partial postback is breaking the connections to my button clicks.  Does this sound like a valid explanation and what can I do about it?

Edit to add, here's what I tried after your suggestion:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
       bindMyButtons();
   });

   var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

   prm.add_endRequest(function () {
       bindMyButtons();
   });

   function bindMyButtons() {
       $('CloseNoticeButton').click(function () {
           'CloseNoticeButton_Click()'
       });

       $('#InBtn').click(function () {
           'InBtn_Click'
       });
       $('#OutBtn').click(function () {
           'OutBtn_Click'
       });
       $('.MyClass').each(function () {
           //do stuff to the MyClass class
       });
   }
```

SOLVED! The suggestion to run it in F12 gave me the answer! I had to add:
EnableEventValidation="false" to my page.  Not entirely sure why but... it seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running it in F12 gave me the answer... many thanks to @VDWWD!  I had to add "EnableEventValidation="false" to may page.  Not sure why but it solved the problem... knock on wood!

Answer (score 1):

You need to rebind the listeners as the DOM is changed due to Partial PostBack. So make sure you rebind controls after a Partial PostBack.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        bindMyButtons();
    });

    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    prm.add_endRequest(function () {
        bindMyButtons();
    });

    function bindMyButtons() {
        $('#myButton').click(function () {
             //hanldle button click
        });

        $('.MyClass').each(function () {
            //do stuff to the MyClass class
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you!  That's essentially what I thought was happening.  I have done essentially no javascript.  I'm working with C# using Telerik controls (buttons etc).  Can you give me a little more handholding to get started?  For example, would "bindMyButtons" be my button click events?

Thank you for your time and help, I do sincerely appreciate it!

Comment: I've updated my answer. But `bindMyButtons` is just a wrapper for everything you do to the buttons before you use the UpdatePanel.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate it... I'm not 100% sure I follow but I'll give it a try and report back with the outcome.  Thank you again!

Comment: OK, I'm very sorry to impose on you again but I edited my question to show what I've tried without success... I'm sure it's idiotic but my JavaScript knowledge is pretty much zero :(

Comment: It looks like we are not talking about the same thing. The things you put in the `bindMyButtons` probaly are the server methods. Not the client side ones. I though you were talking about client side since UpdatePanels remove the script bindings. Why your buttons do not work is difficult to say. But it could be that you do a `Response.Write` for example. You won't see server errors as it is an Ajax post.

Comment: :( :( :( Oh no... another wild goose chase.  I can't for the life of me figure out what's going on.  Worked flawlessly until I added the timer and update panel.  Now it appears that every button works once, and only once which made me conclude it was the partial postback.

Comment: Maybe there is a hint in the browser console (press F12). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352828/updatepanel-triggers-not-firing

Comment: That solved it!  There was a weird error being thrown!  I had to add:
"EnableEventValidation="false" to my page and it works perfectly (I think ;) ).

Thank you so much for your time and perseverance.