# Label floating not working inside updatepanel c#

Tags: jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-5, updatepanel, floating-labels

I am using bootstrap 5 and floating label which is working fine but if i use it inside the update panel and updatepanel refresh then floating label is not working the label display as placeholder does not disappear here is my code`

Product ID
<asp:TextBox ID="txtProductCode" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>

`

Comment: You need to ensure that Bootstrap's JavaScript and CSS files are loaded correctly, and by reinitializing Bootstrap components, such as the floating label, after the UpdatePanel update is complete. You can achieve this by registering a JavaScript function to run after the update and using standard Bootstrap classes like form-label-floating.

Comment: See my answer here. It's the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55479454/5836671

Comment: Manoj Agrawal thanks for your reply but how to do this as all other components are working fine just problem in label floating

Comment: You only should have to use VDWWD suggesting if you using jQuery selectors. If you JUST using css for that label, then it should work ok....